# Android - multiple SDK support in one project?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm creating an app that uses the clipboard manager. Since the way of working with this has changed since API level 10 but I still want it to work on all versions, I would like to use both APIs if possible. I would then like to code some kind logic like this:

```
if androidVersion < 10 
    use code x
else 
    use code y
```

Is this possible?

When I create a project in Eclipse, it either gives me the Android 1.6 jar file or the Android 3.0 jar file depending on the min SDK version I selected. My question is if it's possible to import and use both and if so how? Or will I simply need to make separate projects for different versions? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Sure. Use `android.os.Build.VERSION` to find out what version you are running on and use the appropriate code based upon that.

If you are supporting Android 1.x, the story gets a bit more complicated.

> When I create a project in Eclipse, it either gives me the Android 1.6 jar file or the Android 3.0 jar file depending on the min SDK version I selected.

No, it does not. It gives you 1.6, 3.0, or whatever based on the *build target* you selected. By default, it *also* makes the `android:minSdkVersion` match that, but you can change that, so the `minSdkVersion` is the oldest that you are willing to support and the build target is the oldest whose APIs you are directly referencing.

> My question is if it's possible to import and use both and if so how?

You do not need to import both, and you can't do that anyway.

> Or will I simply need to make separate projects for different versions?

You do not need separate versions.

Comment: Thanks, but when it comes to clipboard handling it does seem that I would need to import both, because the 1.6 code for this has been deprecated. So using the 1.6 library won't let me access the Clipboard manager for 3.0 and vice versa. Do you know any way around this besides making two separate projects?

Comment: Correction to my above comment. I see now that I can actually use the deprecated code for Android 3+ SDKs, but is this really a good idea? Furthermore for Android 3+ I'm trying to make use the new OnPrimaryClipChangedListener that was introduced with SDK 11, so for this I would need to import the new library.

Comment: @mattboy: "I see now that I can actually use the deprecated code for Android 3+ SDKs, but is this really a good idea?" --  you can use the technique I wrote about in the first paragraph of my answer to use the older API on older devices and the newer API on newer devices. "so for this I would need to import the new library" -- you need to set the **build target** to API Level 11.

Comment: OK I got it now! Looks like I had misunderstood my problem. My code was importing both the old and the new packages at the same time which gave a collision error that I misinterpreted as an API version error. Importing only the newest version fixed it. Thanks for your speed and patience!